# Issuing a refund through new Authorize.Net API vs AIM API

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-aim

We are in the process of finally getting off AIM API and moving to the new Authorize.Net API. My question is about refunds. If a charge is sent through AIM, then after we switch, can the refund be sent through Authorize.Net API?  Is the `x_trans_id` and `transactionKey` going to be in sync between the two methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a refund is a refund regardless of which API you are using. As long as you pass in the required information for the refund, as well as meet [the other criteria for a valid refund](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60513298/250259), you can make the initial transaction through the AIM API and make the refund through the new API.